# Increment version number using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
return array(
    'cookieVectorValue' => '---------',
  'cookieStandardKey' => '--------',
  'appVersion' => 20.3,
  'dbconfig' => value(
      )
```

I have a file name called config.txt(file content is shown above).

`appVersion` value should be increased by 1. every time. For example, `appVersion` value `20.3` should be `20.4`. if `appVersion` value is `10`, it should be `11`.

Can someone please tell me how to do it using Unix shell script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want when you run the script they should be incremented by one

Comment: Yes. I want to run the script. Thank you

Comment: What comes after 23.9? 23.10 or 24.0 or something else?

Comment: 23.9 should be changed to 24.0

Comment: As a note, both changing a version number by running a script **and** going from 23.9 to 24.0 would be considered a bad idea where I come from. (Version numbers get bumped manually when work is begun on a new version, and version numbers are considered major.minor, with major only being bumped on major changes, not because there have been nine minor releases.) Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this change the number

```
awk -F'=>|,' -v q="'" '$0~"appVersion"q{$2=0+$2+0.1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }
     $0~"appVersion2"q{$2=0+$2+1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }7' file
```

if you want to save back to the file every time you execute it on the file:

```
awk ... file > newFile && mv newFile file
```

with your data, works like this: (I named file as `f`):

```
kent$  awk -F'=>|,' -v q="'" '$0~"appVersion"q{$2=0+$2+0.1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }
                         $0~"appVersion2"q{$2=0+$2+1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }7' f>newF && mv newF f

kent$  grep appVer f
'appVersion'  => 20.4,
'appVersion2'  => 11,

kent$  awk -F'=>|,' -v q="'" '$0~"appVersion"q{$2=0+$2+0.1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }
                         $0~"appVersion2"q{$2=0+$2+1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }7' f>newF && mv newF f

kent$  grep appVer f                                                                    
'appVersion'   => 20.5,
'appVersion2'   => 12,

kent$  awk -F'=>|,' -v q="'" '$0~"appVersion"q{$2=0+$2+0.1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }
                         $0~"appVersion2"q{$2=0+$2+1;print $1 " => " $2 ",";next }7' f>newF && mv newF f

kent$  grep appVer f                                                                    
'appVersion'    => 20.6,
'appVersion2'    => 13,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
awk '{if(match($0,/appVersion/)>0){ split($0,a,"=>");sub(",","",a[2]);printf("%s => %s,\n",a[1],a[2]+1)}else{print $0}}' file
```

output:

```
return array(
'apiSingnatureVersion' => '001',
'apiAccessKey' => '-----------------',
'apiPrivatekey' => '----------',
'cookieVectorValue' => '---------',
'cookieStandardKey' => '--------',
'appVersion'  => 21.3,
'appVersion2'  => 11,
'dbconfig' => array(
---------------
---------------
)
```

I am not sure what you going to achive, first take a backup of file then do it

to save it :

```
awk '{if(match($0,/appVersion/)>0){ split($0,a,"=>");sub(",","",a[2]);printf("%s => %s,\n",a[1],a[2]+1)}else{print $0}}' file > nwfile;mv nwfile file
```

Comment: hope this has helped you :)

Comment: Thanks dude :) it works..but 20.3 should be 20.4..I had mentioned that in my question. (appVersion value 20.3 should be 20.4 and appVersion2 value 10 should be 11).